# How To Run A Timer As A Service?

Tags: android, timer

I want to run a timer for 24 hours when a switch is switched ON , after 24 hours the switch will be turned off..

But the problem, if the activity is closed or back button pressed the timer will be killed!

After some research I think I need to run the timer as a service maybe? How can I do it??

Thanks Every one.

Here Is My Timer:

```js
 CountDownTimer timert = new CountDownTimer(86400000,1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            String TL =String.format(Locale.US ,"%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(1));

            TimeLeft.setText(TL);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            MainActivity.aSwitch.setChecked(false);
            creditText.setText("Toggle On To Start");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, the back button or closing the Activity will not kill a Service (unless the service was bound but not started).  However it will increase the likelihood its killed for resources.

Secondly, a Service is not the correct way to do long term timers.  Use AlarmManager and set an alarm.  That way even if your service is killed it will be restarted by the system when the timer finishes.

Third-  do you have a static reference to a view object in that code?  I can't even count the number of ways that's a bad idea.  NOTHING outside of an Activity's lifecycle should touch a view.

Comment: But I want to display the count down? if I use AlarmManager, I cant show a 24 hours down counter?

Answer (score 0):

You can also Handler for this one..hope it works

```
public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
            try {
                FestCountdownTimer timer = new FestCountdownTimer(00, 00, 9, 3, 01, 2017);
                new CountDownTimer(timer.getIntervalMillis(), 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                        int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
                        int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                                - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
                        int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                                - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                        int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                        String countdown = String.format("%02dd %02dh %02dm %02ds", days,
                                hours, minutes, seconds);
                        txtTimerDay.setText("" + String.format("%02d", days));
                        txtTimerHour.setText("" + String.format("%02d", hours));
                        txtTimerMinute.setText(""
                                + String.format("%02d", minutes));
                        txtTimerSecond.setText(""
                                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        textViewGone();
                MainActivity.aSwitch.setChecked(false);
        creditText.setText("Toggle On To Start");
                    }
                }.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);



}
```

Remember your `9 is Hours,3 is date,1 is Febraury Month`..Month starts from `0th Index`

FestCoutdownTimer class

```
public class FestCountdownTimer {
    private long intervalMillis;
    public FestCountdownTimer(int second, int minute, int hour, int monthDay, int month, int year) {
        Time futureTime = new Time();
        // Set date to future time
        futureTime.set(second, minute, hour, monthDay, month, year);
        futureTime.normalize(true);
        long futureMillis = futureTime.toMillis(true);
        Time timeNow = new Time();
        // Set date to current time
        timeNow.setToNow();
        timeNow.normalize(true);
        long nowMillis = timeNow.toMillis(true);
        // Subtract current milliseconds time from future milliseconds time to retrieve interval
        intervalMillis = futureMillis - nowMillis;
    }
    public long getIntervalMillis() {
        return intervalMillis;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks alot for your amazing answer, but how can I cancel it at any time?

Comment: you need to use finish() method for that..If my answer satisfies please upvote